# SOAPUI tests reporting in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have integrated SOAPUI with Maven so that my test cases can be executed with Maven build.

It works fine.

But this integration does not create any formatted report which i can refer to know the test results, like an HTML output.

For the same I added a plugin in my POM.XML (shown below)

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

This creates the report, but it does it for all the junit test cases which are in my project.
I can not see any report on the SOAPUI test case.

How can I make the Surefire report contain the SoapUI test results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got it working in my setup.

The solution is "maven-surefire-report-plugin" converts the "TEST*.xml" in to HTML format which is placed in "/targets/surefire-report".So make sure "soapui-maven-plugin" is placing the output in of the "soapui-maven-plugin" in "/targets/surefire-report" directory.

Please see the sample below

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals><goal>test</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectFile>${baseDirectory}/src/test/integration/resources/Mobile-Ads-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                            <iface>mobileAdsService</iface>
                            <outputFolder>${baseDirectory}/target/surefire-reports/</outputFolder>
                            <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                            <exportwAll>true</exportwAll>
                            <printReport>true</printReport>
                            <testFailIgnore>false</testFailIgnore>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: it should be ${basedir} instead of ${basedirectory}